# Windows Batch: Running a Ruby program opens a cmd window

Tags: ruby, windows, batch-file, cygwin

I basically would like to execute a (Cygwin-) Ruby program by clicking on some icon on my desktop. My first attempt went like this:

- Create a desktop link
- As a link target, have something like

  c:\cygwin64\bin\ruby /path/to/my/ruby/program

This works, but it also opens a window where Ruby "runs in", which is not what I want to have.

If it were ActiveState Perl, I would have a command "wperl", which executes Perl without creating a Window, but such an feature doesn't seem to exist for Ruby, at least not for the Cygwin distribution.

I tried to change the link to

```
cmd /MIN /C c:\cygwin64\bin\ruby /path/to/my/ruby/program
```

hoping, that this would run the window minimized, but same effect as before, so I think I need to program somehow a wrapper script which suppresses the creation of this window. Does anybody know how this can be done, preferably using the Windows Batch language or some clever commands in the Cygwin tool chain?

Comment: On Windows Ruby, there should be `rubyw.exe` available, I believe. Not on Windows, don't use Cygwin, can't confirm.

Comment: Thanks for telling about rubyw. Good to know, though sadly not available on Cygwin, as you already guessed.